# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning for fillna with MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings, nan

The line with `fillna()` raises the warning even though it is not performed inplace. Why is that?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


tuples = [('foo', 1), ('foo', 2), ('bar', 1), ('bar', 2)]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 4), columns=index)
df.loc[0, ('foo', 1)] = np.nan

# this works without warning
# df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, np.nan, 3], 'bar': [np.nan, 22, 33]]})  

df1 = df[['foo', 'bar']]
# df1 = df[['foo', 'bar']].copy()  # this does not help
filled = df1.fillna({'foo': 100, 'bar': 200}, inplace=False)
```

The problem does not appear if `foo` and `bar` are ordinary columns, not multiindexed.

Comment: `df1 = df[['foo', 'bar']].copy()` ?

Comment: Throws warning too

Comment: I just copy, paste and run your code in my Jupyter Notebook but there is no warning appear. Why did it happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **false positive**, the warning is not supposed to be raised here. I think the issue is that `fillna` doesn't understand that "foo" and "bar" apply to specific levels of your MultiIndex columns.

I would recommend calling `fillna` inside `GroupBy` as a workaround until this functionality is implemented.

```
fill = {'foo': 100, 'bar': 200}
df1.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(fill[x.name]))

          foo                 bar          
            1         2         1         2
0  100.000000  1.040531 -1.516983 -0.866276
1   -0.055035 -0.107310  1.365467 -0.097696
```

Alternatively, to use `fillna` directly, specify a dict of tuples (because, MultiIndex),

```
df1.fillna({('foo', 1): 100, ('foo', 2): 100})

          foo                 bar          
            1         2         1         2
0  100.000000  1.040531 -1.516983 -0.866276
1   -0.055035 -0.107310  1.365467 -0.097696
```

Comment: Thank you. I applied the second solution and it works :) 

But actually, it is not false positive. Under the hood, pandas performed inplace na filling, which can be tracked down in debugger. In some cases it left me with nas unfilled.

Comment: @Rafcik It is a false positive in the sense that the [SettingWithCopyWarning was developed to warn pandas users against bad practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/53954986#53954986) such a chained assignment. No such thing is going on here.